# How to share Image file/link  via ShareKit using Phonegap for iPad

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, cordova, sharekit

How to share Image file/link  via ShareKit using Phonegap for iPad ?

I am able to send message,but wanna to share Image file or url link.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure ShareKit can share using a web view.  Additionally it hasn't been maintained in over a year.  You might want to look at the Socialize SDK(http://www.getsocialize.com) which can help you share links with a few lines of code.

Comment: Thanks Issac A Mosquera, I will fooloow it.